# iterate through a radio buttons group and get their labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

i want to iterate through a group of radio buttons generated dynamically and get their labels, but when i attempt to print their values nothing appears, see this script demo for an example http://jsfiddle.net/HaBhk/20/ and here's my html where the generated buttons will go

```
<div data-role="content"> 
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="true">
    <h1>AddVote</h1>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain" >
  <input type="text" name="name" id="question" value=""  /><br>
   <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >
         <label for="name"><a href="" id="AddButton" data-role="button"
  data-icon="plus">Add</a><a href="" id="RemoveButton" data-role="button" 
  data- icon="delete">Delete</a>

        </label>
        <input type="text" name="option" id="option" value=""  /><br>

        </div>

    <div  data-role="fieldcontain">
     <form name="OptionsForm" id="InputForm" method="get">
    <div id="after" data-role="controlgroup">
    /////Generated radio buttons goes here
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <a href="#approve" id="publishButton" data-role="button" 
     data-inline="true"data-transition="flip">Preview</a>
     </div><!-- /content -->
```

below is my script to get radio buttons values:

```
$('#publishButton').click(function(){
    var result
var y=document.getElementById('question').value
var form='<Question value=' + y + '/>'+'<br>'
alert(form);
$('input:radio').each(function() {
    var value=$('input:radio').val()
    '<option value='+value + '/>'+'<br>'
    alert(result);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code that will return the relevant labels for the radio options.

```
var labels = [];
$('input:radio').each(function(){
  labels.push($('label[for='+$(this).attr('id')+']').text());
});
alert(labels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HaBhk/24/

```
<input type="text" name="option" id="option" value=""  /><br>
<div id="AddButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Add</div>
<div id="RemoveButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true">remove</div>
<div id="publishButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true">publish</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><legend>Choose an Option:</legend><br><br>
        <div id="after">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function createRadioElement(elem, label, checked) {
    var id = 'option1_' + label;
    $('#after').append($('<div><input type="radio" name="option1" id="'+id+ '" value="1"/><label for="' + id + '">'+label + '</label></div>'));
}

$('#AddButton').click(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('option').value;
    createRadioElement(this, $('#option').val());
});
$('#RemoveButton').click(function() {
    $('#after').children().children("input[checked='checked']").parent().remove();
});

$('#publishButton').click(function() {
    var result;
    $('#after input:radio').each(function() { // only radio buttons in #after
        var value = $(this).next('label').html();
        alert(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: For knowledge sake, it could have been done using `$('input:radio + label').each` and directly `$(this).text()`

Comment: Oh and copy/paste your specific code in your answer, it's really better than only a link

Comment: It's really better posting your own answer. I think I helped way more than you.

Comment: Your answer is good, it's just that if someday fiddle is dead or remove your test, someone looking for the answer won't have it. Hold your horses.

Comment: i have too many radio buttons in my webApp, i want to target only the generated radio buttons in the (#after) div?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#publish').click(function () {
    var labs = $(':radio + label'),
        alertString =[];
    for (var i = 0, labLen = labs.length; i < labLen; i += 1) {
        alertString[i] = labs[i].id;                      
    };
    alert(alertString.join("\n"));            
});
```